# How to comprehend - Locking is not required for any other reason while the variable is being accessed

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

From book "Java Concurrency in Practice" page 26:

> You can use volatile variables only when all the following criteria are met:
>
> - Writes to the variable do not depend on its current value, or you can ensure that only a single thread ever updates the value;
> - The variable does not participate in invariants with other state variables

and

> - **Locking is not required for any other reason while the variable is being accessed.**

What's the meaning of the last bit?

Comment: That's known as "CYA".

Comment: Of course, the whole section, as quoted, seems bogus. You certainly *can* use volatile variables in other situations, *if you also use appropriate locking*.  (This condition may be implied by context not shown above, of course.)

Comment: The context is definitely "you can use volatile variable *instead of locks*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last point is the least technical one: it simply states that you need locks... if you need locks. It is here just for completeness in order to make the list as a whole comprehensive. You may need locks for any number of reasons which fall outside the scope of the memory visibility/atomicity aspects which are discussed in this section.

Comment: Does it mean that If something needs to be locked before the variable is updated, then using a volatile variable is the wrong mechanism ?

Comment: It means that, if something needs to be locked before the variable is updated, you must not remove the lock (you can make the variable volatile---it won't hurt, it's just pointless). Which is kind of obvious anyway and could have gone without saying, but it had to be stated to minimize the chance of complaints by literal-minded readers.

Comment: Ok got it, but now I feel volatile are pointless and I wonder if there are enough use cases of volatile ? If yes then do point me to them, for I really want to decide when to use atomic and when to use volatile.

Comment: A simple usage is for signaling across threads using a `boolean` flag. A more advanced usage is sharing whole object graphs by safe publication of a reference through a volatile variable. This later use case was in fact the prime motivator for the revised `volatile` semantics as of JLS, 3rd edition.

Comment: When you say "atomic" above, do you refer to classes in the `java.util.concurrent.atomic` package? If so, then the decision between them and `volatile` is simple: if all you are ever going to call is `get` and `set` on them, then a volatile var is enough and simpler to use. Atomic containers are all about atomic Compare-and-Swap operations.